# Proof that all functions from M to M being continuous implies all subsets being clopen

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I've been. working through a book in Real Analysis and would like help on a particular problem. I need to prove that if a metric space $M$ exists such that every function $f:M\rightarrow M$ (both $M$s having the same metric) is continuous, then every subset of $M$ is clopen. I'm thinking it has something to do with continuous functions preserving open and closed sets, but am having trouble connecting the dots fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $M$ has at least two points (otherwise it is trivial) $a,b$, Let $S$ a subset distinct of $M$ and not empty and $T$ its complementary $f$ such that $f(s)=a, s\in S, f(t)=t, t\in T$, $d(a,b)=r>0$, $f^{-1}(B(a,r/2)=S$ is open and $f^{-1}(B(b,r/2)=T$ is open. This implies that $S$ is open and closed.